# How to wrap parent DIV around scaled child DIV

Tags: css

I have a parent div wrapped around a scaled child div. The child div starts off with `transform:scale(0,0);` & expands to `transform:scale(1,1);` when a button is clicked.

```
.content-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddf;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:scale(0,0);
  transform-origin:top; 
  transition:transform 1s ease-out; 

}

.content.open {
  transform:scale(1,1);
}
```

However the parent div `content-wrapper` stays at the same size of the child div `content` - even when the child is "closed".

[image]

The desired behaviour is when the child div is closed the parent div shrinks to only wrap around the button.

[image]

[JSFiddle of Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/ztxa5kwu/28/)

Is it possible to wrap the parent div around the child div when it's "closed" in this example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.content {

    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform:scale(0,0);
    transform-origin:top; 
    transition:transform 1s ease-out;

    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0; width: 0;
}

.content.open {
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto; width: auto;
    transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

Edit: Play with this:

```
.content {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin:top;


    transition: transform 1s ease-out, max-width 0.5s ease-out 0.4s, max-height 1s ease-out;
    transform: scale(0,0); max-width: 0; max-height: 0;
}

.content.open {
    padding: 10px;

    transition: transform 1s ease-out, max-width 1s ease-out, max-height 8s ease-out;
    transform: scale(1, 1); max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px;
}
```

Comment: That's close - unfortunately the outer box jumps, rather than transitions to the new size: http://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/ztxa5kwu/108/

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little challenging because the background color is attached to the content container. I would remove the background color from the main container, then make it a separate div positioned `absolute`

```
<div class="content">
    ...
    <div class="content-bg"> //contains your background color
```

then manipulate that based on your click handler.

I've updated the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ztxa5kwu/90/

CSS for the new div:

```
.content-bg{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ddf;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

Notice the `transform-origin: bottom right;` to scale the background towards your button. In the JSFiddle, I made the button take on a border the same color as the background, but you could easily edit the size of the new `<div class="content-bg"></div>` to fit around your button.

Hope that helps, and gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realised I maybe wasn't very clear about the desired behaviour. I need the button to be in the top-left corner & then move out to the top-right as the content expands.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this comment on an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css#comment26204296_17260048):

> This method only partially achieves the desired effect but doesn't
>   actually remove the space. **The transformed box acts like a
>   relatively positioned element - the space is taken up no matter how it
>   is scaled**. Check out this jsFiddle which takes your first one and
>   just adds some bogus text at the bottom. Note how the text below it
>   doesn't move up when the box height is scaled to zero. – animuson♦ Jul
>   29 '13 at 20:37

So with that in mind I used the max-height/ max-width hack to get something close to what I was after: http://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/ztxa5kwu/176/

```
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:scale(0,0);
  transform-origin:top; 
  transition:all 1s ease-out; 
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;  
}

.content.open {
  transform:scale(1,1);
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```